# Finding the volume of $(x-4)^2+y^2 \leqslant 4$

Tags: integration

Calculate the volume of the ring-formed body you get when the circle formed area $$(x-4)^2+y^2 \leqslant  4$$ rotates around the y-axel.

The answer should be: $32\pi^2$

My approach was:

$$ \pi \int_2^6 \left(\sqrt{(x-4)^2-4}\right)^2 dx $$

but I suspect I've the wrong approach. Partly because I don't get a square $\pi$ in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately your approach is wrong.

*This is a normal approach*: We need to separate the circle into two curves as
$$x=4\pm\sqrt{4-y^2}=x_{\pm}.$$
Also, rotating around $y$-axis means that we need to have integral about $y$. So,
$$\begin{align}V&=\int_{-2}^{2}\pi (x_+)^2dy-\int_{-2}^{2}\pi (x_-)^2dy\\&=\pi\int_{-2}^{2}(x_++x_-)(x_+-x_-)dy\\&=\pi\int_{-2}^{2}8\times 2\sqrt{4-y^2}dy\\&=16\pi\times \color{red}{\int_{-2}^{2}\sqrt{4-y^2}dy}\\&=16\pi\times \color{red}{\frac{2^2\pi}{2}}\\&=32{\pi}^2.\end{align}$$

Here, $\color{red}{2^2\pi/2}$ represents the half of the area surrounded by $x^2+y^2=4$.

Comment: How do you find the integration limits?

Comment: I also don't get how you go from $\int \sqrt(4-y^2) dy$ to $\frac{2^2 \pi}{2}$

Comment: @iveqy: For the first, every point $(x,y)$ on the circle satisfies $-2\le y\le 2$. For the second, setting $x=\sqrt{4-y^2}(\gt 0)$ gives you $x^2+y^2=4$, so $\int_{-2}^{2}\sqrt{4-y^2}dy$ represents what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @iveqy: Is there anything unclear? I'll add some more explanation if you want:)

Comment: no I got it, thanks =)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I thought I had. It's now accepted.

Answer (score 3):

An easier approach is to see that the body generated is a **torus**, and its volume is given by

$$V = 2\pi^2Rr^2$$

where $R=4$ is the distance from the center of the ring to the center of the torus, and $r=\sqrt{4}=2$ is the radius of the ring. Hence:

$$V = 2\pi^2\cdot4\cdot2^2 = 32\pi^2$$

Answer (score 3):

You may also use [Volumes of Revolution](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithRings.aspx) and then get the following integral:

$$2\times\int_2^62\pi x\sqrt{4-(x-4)^2}dx=32\pi^2$$

[image]

Comment: What application you use for the illustration? (+1)

Comment: @AdiDani: As usual it is Maple